# Matrix inside Matrix, name of matrix only

Tags: matrices

I want to draw a matrix, in this example, a 7x7 one, with numbers on the outside, but a 3x3 matrix in the core, as shown in the hand drawn picture below. I don't want to write out the inside 3x3 matrix, I just want write the name of it (A_c - B_c * K_c).

I know there are many other questions asking how to draw a matrix inside a matrix, but I couldn't find one where I didn't have to write the actual contents of the inside matrix.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try package nicematrix: https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en . Have a look inside its manual. What you want to do can be done e.g. using the \Block statement of this package. // For the outer and inner braces, they come as rectangular, rounded, none etc. with nicematrix.

Comment: Hmm, I actually want a 17x17 matrix (for the example I drew a 7x7 one for simplicity). I'm using overleaf and it is telling me that I'm trying to use more columns than the emergency stop :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose a solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[ 
    \left[\begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \bigstrut[t]\\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \begin{block}{cc[ccc]cc}
        0 & 0 & & & & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{A_c-B_cK_c} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & & & & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{block}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\[-2ex]
    \end{blockarray}\right]
        \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, I found this solution to be the easiest and work the best for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[columns-width=4mm]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \Block{3-3}{A_c-B_cK_c}
          &   &   & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &   &   &   & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &   &   &   & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{3-3}{5-5}]
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

An idea is to “guess” a suitable amount of additional intercolumn space to accommodate the rather big `A_c-B_cK_c`. I tried a bit and found out that 3pt fits the bill for the standard font and 10pt size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} & 0 & 1 \\
\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} &
\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} &
\hidewidth\begin{bmatrix}
\\
A_c-B_cK_c \\
\\
\end{bmatrix}\hidewidth &
\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} &
\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \\
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{matrix} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix} 4 & 5 & 6 \end{matrix} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `\hidewidth` on either side, the central block turns out to be “invisible” as far as spacing is concerned, but still printed.

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't think of putting together matricies like that to mimic 1 big matrix, thanks!